# Pass a variable into execute process task in SSIS which will use the variable inside the .script winscp file

Tags: sql-server, ssis, winscp

In a SSIS package there is a .script winscp file.

The goal of the package is to run the script into while the values inside the script file changes based on the parameter value that is being passed.

How do I call a variable from SSIS package inside the .script file using execute process task to run that .script file? Which area of the execute process task can I select the variable?

The parameter is a variable value which dynamically changes value based on a table from sql as it loops through each record.

Variable = first

.script winscp file code

```
open FTPsite
cd window/%Variable%
lcd door/%Variable%
get %Variable%.txt
close
exit
```

When the variable value is first the path should change to be
window/first
door/first
first.txt

Eventually next loop variable value is second the path will change to
window/second
door/second
second.txt

How do I do this?